# param.substring not a function- web3.js, ganache

Tags: solidity, web3js, ganache

I get a param.substring is not a function error when trying to call a smart contract function (deployed using ganache and truffle).

This is my code.

```
 const  web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
   const MyContract = new web3.eth.Contract(ABI, ContractAddress);
   console.log(MyContract);

   const create= await MyContract.methods.createToken(hash,letterid).send({ from: window.ethereum.selectedAddress });
```

This is the error.

[image: This is the error.]

please help!

ganache version- 2.5.4
web3 version- 1.7.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`param.substring` is not a function is an error associated with parsing data that is not of type string as one. Check where your ABI is defined and ensure the JSON code is parsed `.toString()`.

If that is already the case, kindly check if Metamask is installed in your browser.